# Как дождаться ответа post запроса oktttp и считать ответ?

Tags: java, post, android-asynctask, okhttp

Всем привет, делаю пост запрос с помощью библиотеки okhttp, запрос выполняется корректно и ответ так же выдается корректно, ниже примерный код который создает объект подключения к серверу, пример:

```
ServerInteraction ServerInteractionReg = new ServerInteraction("url",
            "{\"username\" " + ":\"" + getUsername() + "\", \"password\" :" + "\"" + getUserpassword() + "\"" + "}",getContext());
    ServerInteractionReg.execute();
```

Запрос выполняется в AsyncTask. Основная задача дождаться выполнения потока и затем получить ответ, всё это после вызова метода execute(), например геттером

```
ServerInteractionReg.getResponse();

Код обработки post запроса 

 @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
    try {
        PostQuery();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    //
}

    @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
    try {
        PostQuery();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String PostQuery() throws IOException {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String json = getJson();
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(getUrl())
            .post(body)
            .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
```

Comment: Используй RETROFIT2 и там пиши callback методы
ASYNC TASK - не рекомендуется к использованию, так как из за него возникает утечка памяти

Comment: @Санаев спасибо, и всё же, чистый async task безнадежен ? Могу ли я из этого кода получить то что нужно? Пусть и с утечкой памяти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `ServerInteraction` - это ваш наследник `AsyncTask`, то можно так:

```
public class ServerInteraction extends AsyncTask {
    private CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
        try {
            return PostQuery();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        completableFuture.complete(s);
    }

    public CompletableFuture<String> getResult() {
        return future;
    }

    ...
}


ServerInteraction serverInteraction = ...;
serverInteraction.getResult()
                 .thenApply(s -> {
                     // Делайте с полученной строкой, что хотите
                 });
```

Только зачем этот костыль, если можно в `onPostExecute` выполнить все необходимые операции с полученным результатом?

Comment: Спасибо, то что мне нужно :)